# Difference between an IDE console and a terminal

Tags: java, console, terminal

I am using linux, for the first time in my life. But I am not able to understand the difference between a Java (Eclipse) console and the linux terminal.

Can anybody please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A terminal is a program that provides you with access to a linux shell.  A console is an eclipse window where output is printed by programs run by eclipse.